# Prove that there is a unique homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z} [i]$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, gaussian-integers

> Prove that there is a unique homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z} [i]$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm struggling to show uniqueness here. In the past I have shown that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1+i)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and from this past work I am convinced that the homomorphism in question is in fact

$$
x+yi \mapsto x-y \mod 2.
$$

How do I even begin to show uniqueness here? Thanks in advance.

Edit: To clarify, we are working with only commutative rings with unity in our course, and our definition of a ring homomorphism includes the clause that $\phi(1) = 1$.

Comment: Are you considering only ring homomorphisms that must send $1$ to $1$? Because, otherwise, there’s always the zero map.

Comment: Ah yes, that is part of our definition of a homomorphism. Thanks for asking

Comment: But if your ring homomorphisms must send $1$ to $1$, then the action of any homomorphism on $\mathbb{Z}$ is fixed, and you just need to decide where $i$ goes. Since $1+i^2 = 0$, then $f(i)^2$ must cancel out $f(1)$, which means $f(i)^2=1+2\mathbb{Z}$, and from there you only get one choice.

Comment: $1$ must go to $1$ in a unital ring homomorphism.  Where can $i$ go to? Either to $0$ or $1$, but $i^2=-1$ must go to $-1\equiv1\pmod2$.

Comment: Please put the information on homomorphisms (that you are looking at ring homomorphisms that send $1$ to $1$) into the question. Not everyone reads all the comments.

Comment: Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only true if $1$ is sent to $1$. If that is the case, let $f$ be the homomorphism. Then $f(i)^2=f(-1)=-f(1)=1$, hence $f(i) =f(-i) =1$. Since the ring is generated by $1$ and $i$, the homomorphism is completely determined.